# Find first matching pair within dataframe and flag both

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to find matching pairs within my data on multiple criteria. For every 'Code B', I want to find *one* corresponding 'Code A' where the city, start, and days fields are equal. As soon as a pair is found, both rows should be marked 'Used'.

Starting dataframe:

```
City  Code  Start    Days
ATL   A     5/15/17  1
ATL   A     5/15/17  1
ATL   A     5/15/17  2
ATL   A     5/16/17  1
ATL   A     5/16/17  3
BOS   A     5/15/17  1
ATL   B     5/15/17  1
ATL   B     5/15/17  2
ATL   B     5/16/17  1
ATL   B     5/16/17  1
```

Final dataframe:

```
City  Code  Start    Days Status
ATL   A     5/15/17  1    Used
ATL   A     5/15/17  1
ATL   A     5/15/17  2    Used
ATL   A     5/16/17  1    Used
ATL   A     5/16/17  3
BOS   A     5/15/17  1
ATL   B     5/15/17  1    Used
ATL   B     5/15/17  2    Used
ATL   B     5/16/17  1    Used
ATL   B     5/16/17  1
```

I have been trying to use iterrows(), but haven't been able to get it to work. I can't get it to only assign the 'Used' value to one matching instance.

Comment: May you post your best code so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is goofy and non-optimized... but I have to go have lunch.. so here you go

```
d1 = df.assign(Count=df.groupby(df.columns.tolist()).cumcount())
d2 = d1.set_index(d1.columns.tolist()).assign(X=1)

f = lambda x: x.astype(bool)

d3 = d2.X.unstack('Code', fill_value=0).all(1).compress(f).rename('Status')

d4 = d1.join(d3, on=['City', 'Start', 'Days', 'Count'])

d4.assign(Status=d4.Status.replace(True, 'Used').fillna('')).drop('Count', 1)

  City Code    Start  Days Status
0  ATL    A  5/15/17     1   Used
1  ATL    A  5/15/17     1       
2  ATL    A  5/15/17     2   Used
3  ATL    A  5/16/17     1   Used
4  ATL    A  5/16/17     3       
5  BOS    A  5/15/17     1       
6  ATL    B  5/15/17     1   Used
7  ATL    B  5/15/17     2   Used
8  ATL    B  5/16/17     1   Used
9  ATL    B  5/16/17     1
```

Comment: Thanks so much, piRSquared! This is awesome. I understand how most of this code works, but it introduces a few new concepts to me. What's the purpose of the .assign(X=1) in d2? Can you break down what is happening to create d3?

Comment: @swysell I pushed every column into the index and in order for my `unstack` to work, I needed something in the dataframe... I chose to put a new column named `'X'` with a value of `1`.  This in turn works out when I use `unstack` with a `fill_value` of  `0`.  This allows me to use `all(1)` which only produces `True` values if the entire row is `1`.

Answer (score 1):

I use `groupby` to group `City`, `Start` and `Days` first then apply function to mark the `Used` in each group (note that it's not optimized yet).

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import chain

df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['ATL', 'A', '5/15/17', 1],
    ['ATL', 'A', '5/15/17', 1],
    ['ATL', 'A', '5/15/17', 2],
    ['ATL', 'A', '5/16/17', 1],
    ['ATL', 'A', '5/16/17', 3],
    ['BOS', 'A', '5/15/17', 1],
    ['ATL', 'B', '5/15/17', 1],
    ['ATL', 'B', '5/15/17', 2],
    ['ATL', 'B', '5/16/17', 1],
    ['ATL', 'B', '5/16/17', 1]], 
    columns=['City', 'Code', 'Start', 'Days'])

df.loc[:, 'Status'] = ''
```

This is the function to mark row `A` and `B`

```
def mark_used(gdf):
    marked_a, marked_b = False, False
    df_marked = []
    if len(gdf) > 1:
        for _, row in gdf.iterrows():
            if row['Code'] == 'A' and not marked_a:
                row['Status'] = 'Used'
                df_marked.append(row)
                marked_a = True
            elif row['Code'] == 'B' and not marked_b:
                row['Status'] = 'Used'
                df_marked.append(row)
                marked_b = True
            else:
                df_marked.append(row)
    else:
        for _, row in gdf.iterrows():
            df_marked.append(row)
    return df_marked
```

Then just apply the written function to each group of dataframe

```
ls = [mark_used(gdf) for gid, gdf in df.groupby(['City', 'Start', 'Days'])]
df_marked = pd.DataFrame(list(chain.from_iterable(ls)))
df_marked.sort_index() # sort index back
```

Comment: Thanks, titipata. This almost works (and does work for the example I gave), but it doesn't find the second instance of a 'Code B'.

Such as this dataframe:

df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['ATL', 'A', '5/15/17', 1],
    ['ATL', 'A', '5/15/17', 1],
    ['ATL', 'A', '5/15/17', 2],
    ['ATL', 'A', '5/16/17', 1],
    ['ATL', 'A', '5/16/17', 3],
    ['BOS', 'A', '5/15/17', 1],
    ['ATL', 'B', '5/15/17', 1],
    ['ATL', 'B', '5/15/17', 1],
    ['ATL', 'B', '5/15/17', 2],
    ['ATL', 'B', '5/16/17', 1],
    ['ATL', 'B', '5/16/17', 1]], 
    columns=['City', 'Code', 'Start', 'Days'])

Comment: I see. So in this case, you want the last row to be marked as `Used` also?

Comment: I have `marked_a, marked_b` as a flag in my code where it will mark the first row of Code A/ Code B, it sees accordingly. So in this case, it's going to mark only one row of Code A and one row of Code B. However, you can remove `marked_b = True` in the function in order to always mark Code B with the same City/Start/Days.